# Async.retry executes immediately before waiting for interval

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

```
async.retry({times : 25,interval : 30000},myFunction.bind(functionData),function(err,results){
console.log("===================================")
console.log("Async function finished processing")
return;
})
```

myFunction is called immediately and that too 5 times which is default. also there is no waiting period between calls

Comment: can you show the code for `myFunction`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a version issue I think.

Older versions of `async.retry` can only be called with a number as the first agument (eg see the [v1.2.0 docs](https://github.com/caolan/async/tree/v1.2.0#retry))

It does not accept the `opts` object. So if you pass it in instead of a number for the first argument, it defaults to no interval and a retry count of 5.

I had this same issue using v0.9.0 of the library, updating to v1.4.2 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The retry is dependent on the callback within your function. If the first argument of the callback is not falsy, then it will retry based on your `times` and `interval` settings. For example:

```
var async = require('async');
var count = 0;
var functionData = { some: 'data' };
var myFunction = function(callback, results) {
  console.log(++count);
  process.nextTick(function() {
    if (count < 5) { // Fail 5 times
      return callback({ message: 'this failed' }, null);
    }
    callback(null, { message: 'this succeeded' });
  });
};

async.retry({times : 25, interval : 1000}, myFunction.bind(functionData), function(err, results) {
  console.log("===================================")
  console.log("Async function finished processing")
  return;
});
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
===================================
Async function finished processing
```

With a 1 second interval between each attempt

Comment: async.retry(opts,function(callback){
                            console.log("XXXX");
                            return callback(new Error("sda"));
                        },function(err){
                            callback(err);
                        });

Comment: problem is async.retry executes 5 times even when i am using {times : 25, interval : 60000}

Comment: apart from the undefined `callback`, the snippet you pasted in you're 1st comment works as expected for me. I.e. it retries 25 times.

Comment: try lowering the interval to test it. maybe your getting a timeout elsewhere after waiting for 5 minutes?